# updating path creates write conflict in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongo-shell

Why use of $[] with $ is causing write conflict ?

```
db.projectionTesting.updateOne({"metaData.title": "BCDe"} , {$set : {
                                  "metaData.0.title" : "efde" , 
                                   "metaData.$[].hasUpdateddd": 76
}} )
```

```
 WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 40,
    "errmsg" : "Updating the path 'metaData.$[].hasUpdateddd' would create a conflict at 'metaData'",
    "op" : {
        "q" : {
            "metaData.title" : "BCDe"
        },
        "u" : {
            "$set" : {
                "metaData.0.title" : "efde",
                "metaData.$[].hasUpdateddd" : 76
            }
        },
        "multi" : false,
        "upsert" : false
    }
}) :
```

Why use of $[] with $ is causing write conflict ?

if these are working fine then why not the above one. I want to know what exactly the problem is with the use of $[] with $ in while performing updateOperation

```
 db.projectionTesting.updateOne({"metaData.title": "BCDe"} , 
                                 {$set : {"metaData.0.title" : "efde" , 
                                          "metaData.$.hasUpdateddd": 76}} )
```

```
 db.projectionTesting.updateOne({"metaData.title": "BCDe"} , 
                                 {$set : {"metaData.$.title" : "efde" , 
                                           "metaData.$.hasUpdateddd": 76}} )
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure consistency among replica set members, MongoDB replication requires that operations added to the oplog be idempotent.  To achieve this update operations such as `$inc`, `$dec`, and most array operations are stored in the oplog as `$set` with the new value of the field.

When combining 2 updates using `metaData.$`, you are making updates to one specific element.

When combining `metaData.0` and `metadata.$[]` you are making unrelated updates a single element and to the entire array.

The query executor has not been given logic to be able to ensure an idempotent operation in that situation, so it balks with a write conflict.